# Connecting to wamp server externally

Tags: image, apache, wampserver

I have created a website on wamp server and am trying to access it from another computer on my network. I have already created a virtual host and am able to connect to the website via http://project1 but the images are not loading. The image path is under localhost/project1/... which, I think, is why it is not loading. It seems like every time I type in my (server) ip address / my project name it defaults to localhost / my project name and then says localhost refused to connect. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Funny I actually read both of those already. I am figuring it has to do with the comment on the answer from the first link you posted from Ezeewei, that the database links are based on localhost but I do not know how to change them/tell the website to use those links

Comment: You should create the VH before developing your site, not after. Then this would not happen

Comment: Is there a way to correct the links?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the links in the "href" tags to something more domain independent like

```
<a href="/images/image.jpg> click here </a>
```

This will make your links domain independent, so if your domain is localhost the link will be localhost/images/image.jpg

if your domain is "project1" then it will look like this : 
project1/images/image.jpg

**Note :**
Make sure to use the leading slash / otherwise for example if you are in this page 
project1/page.html

and inside it there is href like this :

```
<a href="images/image.jpg> click here </a>
```

the final link will be: `project1/page.html/images/image.jpg`

Comment: I am using wordpress to handle all of the images and so when I upload them they all appear in the media section. They load for the local computer (the one running the wamp server) but do not load when connecting with another computer. I don't think I can edit the path of the individual images seperately

Comment: this is a problem with wordpress please check : 
https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/remove-domain-name-from-media-upload-urls-and-internal-links
and 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-update-urls-when-moving-your-wordpress-site/